# Read stdin from a NodeJS app deployed to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, terminal, stdin

I'm working on a NodeJS server application (NodeJS/Express/Socket.io). It also uses readline to provide a debug console that grabs commands from stdin. It works fine now, but I suddenly realized that I've never made a console application on Heroku before. I'm nowhere near ready for this app to be deployed yet, so I just tried searching for information about this, but came up blank. Does Heroku offer a way to provide stdin input to a NodeJS server application running on one of its dynos? How does that work? Is there any change I'd need to make in the code when it's time to deploy?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Haven't gotten any answers yet, sadly :(

Comment: I was stuck in a somewhat similar issue, solved it using `heroku run bash`